# Comparables and Wilcard Generics

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Suppose I have the following class (for demonstration purposes)

```
package flourish.lang.data;
public class Toyset implements Comparable<Toyset> {
    private Comparable<?>[] trains;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Toyset o) {
        for (int i =0; i<trains.length; i++) {
            if (trains[i].compareTo(o.trains[i]) < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return 1;
     }  
}
```

The compiler tells me

> "The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type `Comparable<capture#1-of ?>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Comparable<capture#2-of ?>`)"

How can I deal with the fact that I want to put different `Comparables` into trains?
Sure I could remove the parameters and go with raw types, but that seems like a little bit of a cop-out.

EDIT:
Perhaps the example I've given is a little obtuse. What I'm trying to understand is whether generics should always be used with `Comparables`. e.g. If the class of the object I want compare is not known until runtime:

```
public class ComparisonTool {
    public static int compareSomeObjects(final Class<? extends Comparable> clazz, final Object o1, final Object o2) {
        return clazz.cast(o1).compareTo(clazz.cast(o2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(compareSomeObjects(Integer.class, new Integer(22), new Integer(33)));
    }
}
```

If I replace `Comparable` with `Comparable<?>` then the compiler complains (as above) because the two cast operations are not guaranteed to be the same class (capture#1 of ? vs capture#2 of ?). On the other hand, I can't replace them with `Comparable<Object>` either, because then the call in `main()` doesn't match the method signature (i.e. `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>` and not `Comparable<Object>`. Using the raw type certainly 'works', but is this the right approach?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that one instance might have a `Comparable<TrainA>` and the other contain `Comapable<TrainB>` and the `compare` method of `Comparable<TrainA>` will not accept an instance of `TrainB`. This is what you have set up with the wildcard.

Your better bet is to put a common super type in the `Comparable` ie. `Comparable<Toy>` or `Comparable<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring your `trains` field to be of type `Comparable<?>[]`, you're asserting that it's an array of some specific type—and that you don't happen to know *which* type it is. Two different instances of `Toyset` will each have `trains` fields that hold sequences of *some specific type*, but each has a *different* specific type in mind. The compiler is warning you that there's nothing in the code asserting that the specific types of the arrays pointed to be the various `trains` fields in `Toyset` instances will have any subtype or supertype relationship.

In this case, falling back to a raw type is honest; you don't have anything meaningful to say about the type of objects being compared. You could instead try using `Comparable<Object>`, which allows rather weak use of a type parameter.

The design strikes me as odd. I'm assuming it's elided from something much larger. Toy sets can be compared, which in turn depends on a lexicographic comparison of the trains contained in each toy set. That's fine, but why is there no upper bound type that all trains have in common?

Comment: Yes I have taken this somewhat out of context, perhaps that wasn't so clever... What if I want trains to be an array which allows primitives as well? Clearly I'll have to use the wrapper classes, and these don't implement `Comparable`. e.g. `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`. Isn't that a general pattern that classes `T  implement Comparable<T>` and not `Comparable<Object>`?

Comment: Looking at the predicate in your loop (where you call on `Comparable#compareTo()`, you're taking pair-wise elements out of the two `trains` arrays (one from each `Toyset` instance) and feeding one into the other, but you have no idea of the types of either of those two instances. (Also note that there's no guarantee that the "other" `trains` array is as long as the current instance's array, so you're vulnerable to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` there.) You could be comparing a `Caboose` to an `Integer`, and I doubt either knows how to compare itself to the other. Is that your intent?

Comment: That's true. I could be, and I would check that they were the same class at runtime, and throw an exception if that happened. Suppose these are data vectors, and the `compareTo()` method is only called on data vectors which have the same types within their array (i.e. any comparisons between unlike data vectors are guaranteed to fail). I've added a follow up question which hopefully explains more what I'm getting at...